# Update Sql with gridview checkbox

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a gridview set in ASP.Net that has a name and a checkbox.

```
          <h4>Current Instructor</h4>
            <div class="hide-overflow">
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridViewInstructor" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceInstructor" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-striped" ShowHeader="false" EmptyDataText="No Instructor associated to class." DataKeyNames="Instructor">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CBInstructorPrimary" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("Primary")%>' OnCheckedChanged="PrimaryUpdate" AutoPostBack="true" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="InstructorName" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSourceInstructor" DataSourceMode="DataReader"  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HRAgriConnectionString %>"
                    SelectCommand="
                        SELECT a.Primary, a.ClassID, a.Instructor, b.LName + ', ' + b.FName as InstructorName
                        FROM tblClass a
                        LEFT JOIN tblUser b
                        ON a.Instructor = b.UserName
                        WHERE a.ClassID = @classID
                        ORDER BY a.Primary DESC">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="classID" QueryStringField="cid" Type="String" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
```

This makes a gridview table that looks like

[image]

my c# code behind looks like this

```
protected void PrimaryUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //CheckBox activeCheckBox = sender as CheckBox;

    //foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridViewInstructor.Rows)
    //{
    //    CheckBox chkBx = (CheckBox)rw.FindControl("CBInstructorPrimary");
    //    if (chkBx != activeCheckBox)
    //    {
    //        chkBx.Checked = false;
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        chkBx.Checked = true;
    //    }
    //}

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblClass SET [Primary] = @Primary WHERE classID=@classID and Instructor = @InstructorName";
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridViewInstructor.Rows)
            {
                //Get Instructor Name.
                string InstructorName = row.Cells[0].Text;

                //Get the Class Id from the DataKey property.
                classID = Request.QueryString["cid"];

                //Get the checked value of the CheckBox.
                bool Primary = (row.FindControl("CBInstructorPrimary") as CheckBox).Checked;

                //Save to database
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InstructorName", InstructorName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@classID", classID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Primary", Primary);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
        }
    }
}
```

The outcome should be if you check another checkbox it will update the Primary field (which is a bit field) to 1 if checked and all others in that group will be set to 0.  And only 1 checkbox can be checked at a time.  I know I have commented out the top part for now.  I just haven't been able to figure out how to get this working.

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem with this code?

Comment: Instead of trying to essentially update 2 records, the previously selected and the newly selected you could just use 2 sql statements. The first sets them all to 0, the second one updates the selected one.

Comment: @Steve the problem is it doesn't update anything.  There are no Errors it just doesn't update.

Comment: @StephenBrickner I didn't think about that, I will look at ways to try this.

Comment: `@InstructorName` in query string while `@Name` in AddWithValue? And what is that _SalesmanName_ variable?

Comment: @Steve sorry that was a line that I overlooked, I was working on two different pages and had the wrong names in there.

Comment: Did you try to debug this code? Have you checked if the values for _classID_ and _InstructorName_ are correct to match your set of records? This code seems to be correct

Comment: @Steve, yes I have debugged, and yes those do show as correct.  It runs 3 times stopping on each line of the gridview.  Showing the names, the classID and that the primary is set to true.

Comment: Could you change your line with ExecuteNonQuery to _int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();_ and verify with the debugger the value of the variable rows? If it is zero then NO MATCH in the where statement, if >0 then you work on a different database than the one you are looking at.